# Do you have to restart Terminal if you change scrollback settings?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I am executing a long running script that that produces a lot of output on the terminal.

I forgot to set the gnome-terminal scroll back settings to unlimited before I started my script (Edit | Profile Preferences | Scrolling | Uncheck "Limit scrollback to").

If I change the scrollback setting while the script is running, will gnome-terminal immediately apply the new setting and to keep all subsequent output in the terminal, or would I have to interrupt my script, exit terminal, and then restart terminal to get the unlimited scrollback capability?

Comment: Downvoting the question, sorry. It would have probably taken less time for you to try it out and see it for yourself than to post this question, so you're wasting others' precious time for no good reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Gnome-terminal will keep all the subsequent lines if you change the setting accordingly (e.g. make it sufficiently large or infinity).

All changes to Gnome-terminal occurs in-place, from that very time i.e. it is implemented at runtime.